# Is it possible to simulate a button press on an Android application from another application (Android or Desktop)?

Tags: automation, buttons

I need to automatically click on a specific button on an app. Is there a way to do this on a completely controlled environment?

By controlled environment, I mean the phone could be rooted, it could be connected to a desktop machine, any external app could be installed, and any other requirement.

Note: the button is NOT on an exposed activity.

Comment: Yes, the "Accessibility Services" can do that. However Google is planning to remove apps from PlayStore that use this service for controlling other apps for a different reason than helping disabled persons.

Comment: There are also applications for this and lot of other commands for rooted phones.

Answer (score 1):

You can use adb command to simulate touch

`adb shell input tap x y`

where x y are the co-ordinates of the pixels on the screen to be tapped.